# Elastic search Whitespace Analyser and customer analyser with Whitespace Tokeniser

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a custom analyser 'default' in elastic search indexing template with tokeniser as "whitespace". Can I use elastic search in-build Whitespace analyser for this purpose as my default analyser with Whitespace tokeniser and in-build Whitespace analyser will do the same task. In general, which is better to use? Will there be any performance impact?

```
"analysis": {
   "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [whitespace tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) and [whitespace analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) are built-in in elasticsearch

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "whitespace",
  "text" : "multi grain bread"
}
```

Following tokens are generated

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "multi",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "grain",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "bread",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use any of them if you only want to break the text when any whitespace comes. However, when you need to modify the `whitespace`, you should use the `whitespace tokenizer` and the `filters` you want to add. **This is because you can not modify the `whitespace` analyzer.**